# How to compare 2 tables in 2 different databases and only update the values that changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am currently working on an SSIS package that moves tables from one SQL server to another SQL server. My current implementation involves dropping the table at the destination database before creating and copying over the table data again. However, this way there will be a short interval during which the table will not be available at the destination database when I drop and create again. Hence, it would be possible for clients to not have any data/table at all if they happen to access it the same time the package runs. Is there a way I could avoid this lag and only update values that changed without dropping or it is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do incremental load .Please find the steps in below link
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/incremental-load-in-ssis/

Else you can first load the data in staging table like yourtablename_tmp and then drop the actual destination table and rename staging table to yourtablename . This way the gap will be for really short interval.